# Can you solve maximum gap for a chain of elements in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a difficult query I have to make in SQL(postgressql). I have tried to explain the problem below.

I have a chain of elements each having a max gap to next. So I want to calculate the "distance" matrix. So take the following 4 element:

```
example_id,id,max_gap
0,0,2
0,1,5
0,2,
0,3,4
```

then the max_gap between each element should be the following for this example

```
example_id,id,max_gap
0,0,0,0
0,0,1,2
0,0,2,7
0,0,3,
0,1,0,-2
0,1,1,0
0,1,2,5
0,1,3,
0,2,0,-7
0,2,1,-5
0,2,2,0
0,2,3,
0,3,0,
0,3,1,
0,3,2,
0,3,3,0
```

So if any of the elements between two elements have max_gap infinity then the max_gap between the two elements is infinity.

The challenge is to the solve this problem in SQL (since in need to have this in a sql trigger).

The following Python code can be used to create test_cases:

```
from random import randint, random
from itertools import groupby 
n_examples = 100

def generate_examples(n):
    out = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(randint(1,10)):
            max_dist = randint(0,10)
            if random()>0.75:
                max_dist = None
            out.append([i,j,max_dist])
    return out

def max_dist_between_all(example):
    example_id = example[0][0]
    n=len(example)
    return [(example_id,i,j,calc_dist(i,j,example)) for i in range(n) for j in range(n)]

def calculate_max_dist_between_all_examples(examples):
    return [result
            for _, example in groupby(examples, lambda x:x[0])  
        for result in max_dist_between_all(list(example))
      
    ]
    
def calc_dist(i,j,example):
    if j<i:
        i,j = j,i
        sign =-1
    else:
        sign=1
    max_dist = 0
    for k in range(i,j):
        max_dist_between_step = example[k][2]
        if max_dist_between_step is None:
            return None
        max_dist+=max_dist_between_step
    return sign*max_dist

examples =generate_examples(n_examples)        

def print_in_csv(input_, headers):
    print(",".join(headers))
    print("\n".join([",".join(str(e) if e is not None else "" for e in l) for l in input_]))
print_in_csv(examples, ["example_id","id","max_gap"])
print()
print_in_csv(calculate_max_dist_between_all_examples(examples), ["example_id","id","max_gap"])
```

Comment: I don't understand how the fourth column is calculated based on the other columns.  Also, distance -- by mathematical definition -- is not negative.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a self join?

```
select e1.example_id, e1.id, e2.id, e1.max_gap - e2.max_gap
from elements e1 join
     elements e2
     on e1.example_id = e2.example_id
```

Comment: No it is a cumulative sum, so if you want to calculate the max_gap between e1 and e3 then it is e1.max_gap + e2.max_gap